# How Google Cloud determines which packet should route to Premium network tier/Standard tier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Google mentions that

> Premium Tier delivers traffic from external systems to Google Cloud resources by using Google's low latency, highly reliable global network. This network consists of an extensive private fiber network with over 100 points of presence (PoPs) around the globe.

But how do they control the network packet that the packet should go into premium network route rather than the standard network route.

For instance, users make a request from their home internet to mywesbsite.com hosted on the Google Cloud running on Premium network tier.

`mywebsite.com` doesn't tell anything about the network tier. I'm just wondering what piece of information that Google uses to determine/control the route of the network packet.

Comment: When you create for example a LB and use premium tier, GCP will know how to make the route when someome try to reach the endopoint. The same aplies for a VM. Why would you like to know what gcp uses to know what “routing” to use?

Comment: It's just my curiosity. I just want to know how they know it from the network engineering perspective.

Comment: The technology is called **Anycast IP** and **BGP**.  https://sre.google/workbook/managing-load/

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for your info. Why google also offer premium network on regional load balancer that doesn't use Anycase IP? Does that mean BGP alone can achieve this?

Comment: @Turbo Anycast is not required for all services. Premium Tier Network also means that a) traffic stays within Google's network until it **must** exit to the public Internet and b) traffic arrives at the closest POP (Point-of-Presence) to the client and then is routed within Google's backbone.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's not required for all services. But you mentioned that Anycast IP is part of how google determines premium network routing so I was asking for the services that do not use anycast IP if the BGP alone can be used to determine the packet?